# Ng2-imageupload not working with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am using ng2-imageupload to achieve browser image upload in Ionic2 after updating to Ionic3 after selecting an image the `(imageSelected)="selected($event, 0, 1)"` does not trigger the upload function. Also `resizeOptions` cannot be assigned to input component.

```
<input type="file" id="file" image-upload (imageSelected)="selected($event, 0, 1)">
```

Comment: Can you share the Url of "Ng2-imageupload" component?

Comment: found the solution by using the imageUpload directive name solved all the errors. Thanks for all the help!!!